# ROS Kinetic 'catkin_make' Fails because PROJECT_NAME is set to Project

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I have been using ROS Kinetic for a while, and today when I went to make a new catkin workspace following the ROS tutorials page (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) I get a CMake Error stating that PROJECT_NAME is set to Project, which is invalid. I have never run into this issue with any of my other work spaces I have created.

I do not want to mess with *toplevel.cmake* out of fear of screwing up my other work spaces.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:91 (message):
  catkin_package() PROJECT_NAME is set to 'Project', which is not a valid
  project name.  You must call project() before calling catkin_package().
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the above error you are getting. For that what I did is opened my `CMakeLists.txt` and commented the second line which defines the package Name, i.e., `project(package_name)`. After that, I tried to build my package via `catkin_make`, but got below error(see the error inside yellow box):

[image]

Then, I tried to build the same package after uncommenting the above line. This time I was able to build my package(test, in my case) successfully, without any error.

[image]

`CMakeLists.txt` file contains `project()` as well as `catkin_package()` and the former function should be called before `catkin_package()` inside the file. So, `project(package_name)` is either missing from your `CMakeLists.txt` file or is commented.

If it is missing, then manually add it. If it is there, but commented then uncomment it.

Read more about the correct format of `CMakeLists.txt` file from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! This certainly makes sense. I wonder why this is a problem now and never before. When I make a new workspace folder, call it ```test_ws/src```, then I run ```catkin_make``` in the top folder, it creates a ```CMakeLists.txt``` in the src folder like I would expect it to. This file has a sym link to ```/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake```, which also does not have the ```project()``` function call. Should I change ```toplevel.cmake``` ? I ask because I have been warned on more than one occasion to NOT change system files like that.

Comment: Yes the problem seems to be that when I run ```catkin_make``` in a brand new work space, the ```CMakeLists.txt``` file that is generated is a sym link to ```/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake```. No idea how that happened though.

Comment: Welcome. If my answer helped you, please accept it. Thanks. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: To be clear, this does not actual solve my problem, but the accepted answer helped me find the real problem.

Comment: I have not solved the problem. I think the problem is when I run ```catkin_make``` in ```catkin_ws```, a ```CMakeLists.txt``` gets generated that is a symlink to ```/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake```. I am not sure if this is suppose to happen, but I do not know what else would be the problem. I moved to a different computer and the problem is not present, so I assume the problem is my machines configuration. I plan to reinstall everything (after a deadline) to see if the problem persists. Should I marked as not solved?

Comment: So, this `CMakeLists.txt` that you are referring to has been generated in at `/home/user/catkin_ws/src` path ? If yes, this is fine. But, when you create a ros package in `src` directory, then one `CMakeLists.txt` file will also get created inside the package itself, containing package_name as described in my explaination above. So, I think it's fine. But you must be getting above error because of missing/commented `project(package_name)`  line in `CmakeLists.txt` file inside your ros package under `src` directory, not `CmakeLists.txt` file inside `src` directory.

Answer (score 0):

ironically, you'll be running : `sudo apt-get install ros-<distro_name>-catkin to reinstall catkin` because even if u clear your entire workspace the problem will persist due to some symbolic link or something broken in the package which will always result in the same error, upon reinstalling catkin it worked for me, knowing that I had the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had to come answer this because I think I did the same thing OP did. Here's what happened: There are supposed to be **TWO** CMakeLists.txt in your project folder. One lives at `ProjectName/src` and should be read-only and should actually be a link to your `/opt/ros/your-ros-distro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` folder.

If you do like I did, and I'm assuming like OP did, and edit that file, and then use your superuser to **overwrite** that file, then you are (1) breaking all of your catkin projects, because **ALL** of the catkin projects link to this one file, **AND** you're misconfiguring this project because the `CMakeLists.txt` file you're *supposed* to modify actually exists a folder deeper, at `ProjectName/src/ProjectName/`. THIS is where you're supposed to put the `CMakeLists.txt` file that names your project, where your `package.xml` file is supposed to go, etc.

If you use superuser to force-overwrite the read-only `CMakeLists.txt` file then you're going to have a bad day. Fortunately you can fix that file by fixing the `toplevel.cmake` folder, which you can do by reinstalling the catkin package: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-catkin`

And, to put this in terms of OP's question specifically - the `project()` needs to get named at the inner file, the `ProjectName/src/ProjectName/CMakeLists.txt`, because again the root file is **read-only and should never be modified.**